# Search a div and narrow down options

Tags: jquery

I have div with a bunch of cities inside. And it is frustrating when you don't find the city you are looking for.

So I'm trying to add a search bar, to exclude the cities that doesn't match the search string.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="quick city search">
  </div>
</form>
<div id="cities">
    <div id="cities">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=alingsas" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Alingsås</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=borlange" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Borlänge</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=boras" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Borås</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=eskilstuna" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Eskilstuna</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=falun" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Falun</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=goteborg" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Göteborg</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=gavle" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Gävle</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=halmstad" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Halmstad</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=helsingborg" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Helsingborg</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=hudiksvall" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Hudiksvall</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=harnosand" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Härnösand</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=jonkoping" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Jönköping</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=kalmar" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Kalmar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an attempt in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8rp18qb/).

This one with highlight was the reference: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/aSjqT/

**My question is:**
How can i search a div, and exclude strings that is not "searched" for.

Comment: Where is a question in this question?

Comment: I mean what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle do

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        
        $("#cities a").each(function(index) {      
                $row = $(this);            
                var id = $row.text().toUpperCase();           
                //All match
                //if (id.indexOf(value) == -1) {
                //For startWith Match
                  if (!id.startsWith(value)) {
                    $row.hide();
                }
                else {
                    $row.show();
                }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="quick city search">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>
            <div id="cities">
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=alingsas" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Alingsås</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=borlange" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Borlänge</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=boras" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Borås</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=eskilstuna" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Eskilstuna</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=falun" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Falun</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=goteborg" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Göteborg</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=gavle" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Gävle</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=halmstad" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Halmstad</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=helsingborg" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Helsingborg</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=hudiksvall" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Hudiksvall</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=harnosand" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Härnösand</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=jonkoping" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Jönköping</a>
                <a href="http://www.example.com/?city=kalmar" style="font-size: <?php echo mt_rand(5, 40); ?>px">Kalmar</a>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k8rp18qb/2/

Comment: Thanks, but seems as the first string is (alingsås in my fiddle) is always the one thats shows (not being excluded).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible so that the script will search from the beginning of the strings? if i type `st` I will now get both `Eskilstuna` and `Halmstad`. (both of them contain `st`). But say that `stockholm` would exist as an option, only `stockholm` should show. So, search from the beginning of the strings, is that possible?

Comment: For that use `startsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you alot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form class="ui-filterable">
          <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
        </form>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Diana</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Glen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ralph</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Valarie</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> 

    </body>
    </html>
```